# "Login Items" are removed in Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, login-items

Since upgrading to OSX Yosemite, I've run into an issue where several of the apps I've added to 'Login Items' (via preferences) do not launch at startup, and have been removed from 'Login Items' altogether.

I've re-added them only to be bit by the same behavior several times. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same issue just now. I ended up deleting the `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.com.loginwindow.plist` and that fixed it for many people according to the online forum threads, but not me.

Not until I found a little post saying to logout and uncheck the `Reopen windows when logging back in` option did I fix it.

So give that a shot. BTW I'm on 10.10.5 Yosemite, but other OS versions seem affected, too.

Answer (score 0):

What are these apps your are trying to launch at startup?
Did you try to open them manually to check they are running fine with Yosemite?
Have a look at what /Application/Utilities/Console.app outputs right after a startup, it may help.

Answer (score -1):

They design is slightly different in Yosemite but it's definitely there. Head to System Preferences > Users & Groups > Current User > Login Items. You can then select what you'd like to start with your system (see image).

[image]

You can also right click on any icon in your dock, like I do with Chrome below, and select for it to start at startup, which has the same effect.

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question - the problem is that on restart, items I've added to Login Items are removed.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's not what I understood at all. Do you happen to run on a domain where an administrator could push certain configurations to your system?

Comment: No, it's just me.